# Asp Net MVC 5 process multi select search

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to figure out how I can send n selected options to the controller and return a view with those options.

```
public ViewResult SearchAndFilters(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, ViewModel model)
{
    //pagination things

    if (model.CountryFilter != null)
    {
        //person is the list that contains all the "people", and country is a string
        var countries = person.Where(m => model.CountryFilter.Contains(m.Country));
        myViewModel.person = countries.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
    }

    return View("~/Views/Home/SearchAndFilters.cshtml", myViewModel);
}
```

This code works if I send only one country name through `model.CountryFilter`  but if I send 2 or more it only processes one. What would I need to change in order to make my search return all the people that are from country A and B?

This is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchAndFilters", "Person", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryFilter, Model.CountryList, new { @class = "chosen", multiple = "multiple", style = "width: 250px;", data_placeholder = "Countries" })

    </p>

    <input type="submit" name="SearchLists" value="Search" /> 
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `CountryFilter`? (it would need to be `IEnumerable` - e.g. `int[]` or `string[]`). And you can use `@Html.ListBoxFor()` and drop the `multiple = "multiple"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke oh sorry about that, thought countryfilter is in fact a string[]